# When should I use Option.empty[A] and when should I use None in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-option

In Scala, when I want to set something to `None`, I have a couple of choices: using `None` or `Option.empty[A]`.

Should I just pick one and use it consistently, or are there times when I should be using one over the other?

Example:

```
scala> def f(str: Option[String]) = str
f: (str: Option[String])Option[String]

scala> f(None)
res0: Option[String] = None

scala> f(Option.empty)
res1: Option[String] = None
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would stick to `None` whenever possible, which is almost always. It is shorter and widely used. `Option.empty` allows you to specify the type of underlying value, so use it when you need to help type inference. If the type is already known for the compiler `None` would work as expected, however while defining new variable

```
var a = None
```

would cause infering `a` as `None.type` which is unlikely what you wanted.

You can then use one of the couple ways to help infer what you need

```
@ var a = Option.empty[String]
a: Option[String] = None
@ var a: Option[String] = None
a: Option[String] = None
@ var a = None: Option[String] // this one is rather uncommon
a: Option[String] = None
```

Another place when compiler would need help:

```
List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(Option.empty[String])((a, e) => a.map(s => s + e.toString))
```

(Code makes no sense but just as an example) If you were to omit the type, or replace it with `None` the type of accumulator would be infered to `Option[Nothing]` and `None.type` respectively.

And for me personally this is the place I would go with `Option.empty`, for other cases I stick with `None` whenever possible.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer use `None` if talking about a value for example when passing parameter to any function, use `Option.empty[T]` when defining something.

`var something = Option.empty[String]` means `something` is `None` for now but can become `Some("hede")` in the future. On the other hand `var something = None` means nothing. you can't reassign it with `Some("hede")` compiler will be angry:

`found   : Some[String]
required: None.type`

So, this means `None` and `Option.empty[T]` are not alternatives. You can pass `None` to any Option[T] but you can't pass Some[T] to None.type

Comment: But if you assign to None with declaring the type it's equal. x: Option[String] = None. Empty let you set a type.

Answer (score 1):

Following are worksheet exports using Scala and Scalaz .

```
def f(str: Option[String]) = str              //> f: (str: Option[String])Option[String]
f(None)                                       //> res1: Option[String] = None
var x:Option[String]=None                     //> x  : Option[String] = None
x=Some("test")
x                                             //> res2: Option[String] = Some(test)
x=None
x
```

Now using Scalaz ,

```
def fz(str: Option[String]) = str             //> fz: (str: Option[String])Option[String]
fz(none)                                      //> res4: Option[String] = None
var xz:Option[String]=none                    //> xz  : Option[String] = None
xz=some("test")
xz                                            //> res5: Option[String] = Some(test)
xz=none
xz
```

Note that all the statements evaluate in the same way irrespective of you use `None` or `Option.Empty`. How ?

As you can see it is important to let Scala know of your intentions via the return type in the `var x:Option[String]=None` statement. This allows a later assignment of a `Some`. However a simple `var x=None` will fail in later lines because this will make the variable x resolve to `None.type` and not `Option[T]`.

I would think that one should follow the convention. For assignments i would go for the `var x:Option[String]=None` option. Also whenever using None it is good to use a return type (in this case Option[String]) so that the assignment does not resolve to `None.type`.
Only in cases where i have no way to provide a type and i need some assignment done will i go for `Option.empty`

Comment: I can't think of any sense in which "both of them resolve to Option[Nothing]". And as other answers show, they _can't_ always be used interchangeably.

Comment: Yes you are correct i was talking about Scalaz but the meaning was not clear. Thanks. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Even there, you actually get `none[A]: Option[A]`. This is the same type as `Option.empty`, not `Option[Nothing]`; that's _why_ it can be used interchangeably. You only get `Option[Nothing]` if it's used without type argument in a position where Scala can't infer it, same as with `Option.empty`.

Comment: Now i am confused. I see in worksheet   Scalaz's `none` and `Option.empty`  both resolve to `Option[Nothing]`  .  Are you suggesting something else?

Comment: "if it's used without type argument in a position where Scala can't infer it". You normally wouldn't write `val x = none`, but `val x = none[String]` (or use `none` where the compiler expects a specific type, such as `f(none)` in the question).

Comment: agree and updated the answer with current understanding. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `Option[A].empty` simply returns `None`:

```
/** An Option factory which returns `None` in a manner consistent with
 *  the collections hierarchy.
 */
def empty[A] : Option[A] = None
```

I'd say:

1. As you said, be consistent throughout the codebase. Making it consistent would mean that programmers entrying your codebase have one less thing to worry about. *"Should I use `None` or `Option.empty`? Well, I see @cdmckay is using X throughout the call base, I'll use that as well"*
2. Readability - think what conveys the point you want the most. If you were to read a particular method, would it make more sense to you if it returned an empty `Option` (let's disregard for a moment the fact that the underlying implementation is simply returning `None`) or an explicit `None`? IMO, I think of  `None` as a non-existent value, as the documentation specifies:

   ```
   /** This case object represents non-existent values.
    *
    *  @author  Martin Odersky
    *  @version 1.0, 16/07/2003
    */
   ```

Comment: Downvoting, as it doesn't answer the question (whether sometimes one is preferred for reasons other than consistency). Furthermore, the point about an empty option making more or less sense than an explicit None seems cryptic to me.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else pointed out, it's more a matter of personal taste, in which most of the people prefer `None`, or, in some cases, you explicitly need to put the type because the compiler can't infer.

This question can be extrapolated to other Scala classes, such as `Sequences`, `Map`, `Set`, `List` and so on. In all of them you have several ways to define empty state. Using sequence:

- `Seq()`
- `Seq.empty`
- `Seq.empty[Type]`

From the 3, I prefer the second, because:

- The first (`Seq()`) is error prone. It looks like if someone wanted to create a sequence and forgot to add the elements
- The second (`Seq.empty`) is explicit about the desire of having an empty sequence
- While the third (`Seq.empty[Type]`) is as explicit as the second, it is more verbose, so I don't use typically